# A syntax error in print the line of a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print the line of a file , but some syntax error happened . What's wrong with my code?

```
History_Data = open("C:/lottery/Dataset/History.txt","r")

Line = History_Data.readline()
print Line

History_Data.close()
```

The error message shows:

```
PS C:\Temp> python.exe .\1.py
  File ".\1.py", line 5
    print Line
             ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Indeed, please do not post screenshots of text but the text itself instead! And since you seem to be very new with Python: Please have a look at [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), especially regarding naming conventions. TLDR: Use `lowercase_with_underscores` for your vars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Python 3.x, do the following:

```
print(Line)
```

---

```
Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:06:53) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print 1
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print 1
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> print(1)
1
```